# LinkedIn javascript SDK Share Dialog

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

How can I force LinkedIn to always show the share dialog, I am using LinkedIn JavaScript API. My current implementation is like this

```
IN.User.authorize(function(){
  IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
  .method("POST")
  .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
  .result(function(response){
    deferred.resolve(response);
  })
  .error(function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
  });
});
```

If user is logged in and already has authorized the app, text is shared on LinkedIn without showing the share dialog.

I want user to have a look at the content before actually posting in on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the SDK for sharing plugin, then you can just use a raw URL and it should work fine:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this will bring up the prompt for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Prompt works fine:

[image]